# Empty FlatList React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am working on a D&D app with react native. When I try to render the code, the screen is empty and the console.log shows an array.

The code:

```js
    export default () => {
      
        const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
        const [monsters, setMonsters] = useState([])
        console.log(" ~ file: Monsters.js ~ line 10 ~ monsters", monsters)
    
        const fetchMonsters = async () => {
          const response = await fetch('https://www.dnd5eapi.co/api/monsters')
          const data = await response.json()
          setMonsters(data)
          setLoading(false)
        }
    
      useEffect(() => {
        fetchMonsters()
      }, [])
    
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          {loading ? <Text>Cargando...</Text> :
          <FlatList 
            style={styles.list}
            data={monsters}
            renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.name}</Text>}
          />}
        </View>
      );
    }; 
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'flex-start',
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
      },
    });
```

When I fetch the [users API](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users) all the items render in the list, but when I fetch the [monster API](https://www.dnd5eapi.co/api/monsters) the screen shows nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused by the difference in structure of 2 APIs.

**https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users**

It is an array with listing objects.

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    ...
  },
]
```

**https://www.dnd5eapi.co/api/monsters**

It is an Object with array named 'results'.

```
{
  "count":334,
  "results:[
      {
         "index":"aboleth",
         "name":"Aboleth",
             ...
      },
  ]
}
```

So, your code in `fetchMonsters` should be

```
setMonsters(data.results);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's happening because you are storing whole JSON response in your state instead of `results` array inside that just update your `fetchMonsters` function like this and that should do it

```js
     const fetchMonsters = async () => {
          const response = await fetch('https://www.dnd5eapi.co/api/monsters')
          const data = await response.json()
          setMonsters(data?.results)
          setLoading(false)
        }
```